# Bluetooth audio does not work under ssh (but works on the GUI)

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I would like to play audio from my Raspberry Pi to an external bluetooth speaker.

I have successfully connected to the device and, from within the graphical desktop (which I connect with VNC), I can successfully play audio in the bluetooth speakers. However, when I am not using the graphical desktop but log in using SSH, I cannot play the audio over the speakers.

If I open a terminal under the graphical environment, I get this output:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -E 'name:|index'
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.analog-stereo>
  * index: 1
    name: <bluez_sink.C7_01_8E_49_AB_1A.a2dp_sink>
$ aplay file.wav
# audio plays
```

However, when I connect through SSH, I get this:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -E 'name:|index'
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.analog-stereo>
$ aplay file.wav
# no audio  (or, maybe, audio at the jack)
```

Why bluetooth audio is not visible under SSH?

Here are my specs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pi 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/device-tree/model
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1
$ cat /etc/issue.net
Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l
```